# I need a jpql query for hard to understand Many-Many connection

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I'm trying to control access to my entities, for that I need a query of projects$P entities that have many to many relation to projects$Participant, which is associated with df$employees which is associated with sec$user.

I only need a projects$P entities that have participant with userid = :sessionuserId

I've made a scheme to help you understand the connection.

[image]

```
select distinct p
from projects$P p
join p.pParticipants pt
where pt.name.user like :sessionUserId
```

Please help me write a proper query

Answer (score 0):

All right, i solved this lil problem.
This should have worked if :sessionUserId was uuid, instead, :sessionUserId was, for unknown reason string.

```
select distinct p
from projects$P p
join p.pParticipants pt
where pt.name.user.id like :sessionUserId
```

So i had to use different session identificator

```
select distinct p
from projects$P p
join p.pParticipants pt
where pt.name.user.login like :sessionUserLogin
```